# Append Footer Text using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word and c#

Tags: c#

I am using this following code to add footer in currently opened MS Word document.

```
foreach (word.Section wordSection in Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Sections)
            {
                string documentname = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Name;                
                word.Range footerRange = wordSection.Footers[word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
                footerRange.Font.ColorIndex = word.WdColorIndex.wdBlack;                
                footerRange.Font.Size = 7;                
                footerRange.Text = documentname;
            }
```

Its working great. But only problem is its replacing all existing content from footer like page number etc. How do I **append** the document name at the footer so that it does not remove the existing container of the footer ?

Comment: Hello does anyone know how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
footerRange.Text += documentname;
```

New Footer = Existing footer + documentname